# Determining the latest stable Android SDK

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, versioning

What is a reliable process for keeping a project developed in Android Studio up to date as Google releases updates to its Android SDK?

I only want to update to the latest stable releases, not beta releases. For example, at present, I am not interested in the Android 7.1.1 (API 25) SDK, since it's still in preview. Likewise, I don't want a beta version of any Android support library, even if lint tells me one is available.

Specifically, how do I determine which packages to install from the SDK Manager, and how do I determine what versions to specify in `build.gradle` for declarations such as the following?

```
compileSdkVersion xxx
...
targetSdkVersion xxx
...
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:xxx'
```

**Update:** For further background, see the new Android Studio issue, [Lint prompts upgrade to partially distributed SDKs](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=226469), prompted by comment discussion.

Comment: Set `compileSdkVersion` to the highest production API level (presently 24). Set `targetSdkVersion` to whatever makes sense for your app (24 if you're ready for it, lower if you are not). The support libraries major version should match your `compileSdkVersion`, and use the latest minor/patchlevel within that.

Comment: I'm looking for a version-independent process, rather than specific answers just for today. For example, how does one quickly determine that API level 24 is the latest stable these days? Is there a canonical web page that posts this? The support libraries have minor releases. How does one determine their latest stable versions?

Comment: "For example, how does one quickly determine that API level 24 is the latest stable these days?" -- because Android 7.0 shipped, and Android 7.0 is API Level 24 (see `Build.VERSION_CODES`). "Is there a canonical web page that posts this?" -- Android OS releases are covered by many major news outlets. "How does one determine their latest stable versions?" -- it's the highest number, assuming that there is no `-alpha` or similar suffix appended.

Comment: Google doesn't reliably tag their pre-release packages. For example, Android Studio SDK manager lists Android 7.1.1 with no alpha tag or other indication that it's [not baked yet](https://developer.android.com/preview/index.html); you need to go find the appropriate website yourself. Likewise, Android Studio's code analysis warns you if you have a dependency on a support library before 25.0.0, but doesn't mention that 25 is preview. Searching news outlets isn't ideal either because you need to manually sift through updated and out of date articles, especially with point releases like 7.1.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use these links to find the latest. Mostly the android website:

[compileSdk & targetSdk](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/#Platform): Scroll down to platforms table. Both are equal to the latest platform version's API i.e. 27

[supportLibVersion](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions): Whichever one is a stable release

[gradle & plugin version](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-plugin): Be sure to updgrade gradle & plugin from this page

[googlePlayServicesVersion](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project): Scroll to the table and whatever the tailing number is on each row

[buildToolsVersion](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools): Apparently you dont need to declare build tools anymore after gradle version 3.0.0 but just in case you need it

[firebase](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#20180523): Find all libs as needed

I usually set the following in my project level build.gradle and set a variable for it to use in my other build.gradle:

```
ext {
    compileSdkVersion   = xxxx
    targetSdkVersion    = xxxx
    supportLibVersion   = "xxxx"
    buildToolsVersion   = "xxxx"
    googlePlayServicesVersion = "xxxx"
}
```

If you keep those bookmarked you should be able to find the latest for each easily

Answer (score 0):

> I only want to update to the latest stable releases, not beta releases.

With respect to support libraries, alphas and betas are advertised as such in terms of artifact versions. For example, the `ConstraintLayout` libraries are presently `-beta1`, IIRC.

With respect to the Android SDK, the rule for the past three years is that if it is called a "developer preview", it is not what you would consider to be a stable release. If it has a regular Android version number (e.g., 7.0), it is a stable release.

You have expressed concern about Android 7.1, and it is somewhat of an exception to the previous rule. IMHO, Google screwed this up, presumably due to typical executive idiocy. Effectively, API Level 25 is final, as they are already shipping devices (Pixel) that have Android 7.1, and the source code is up in the AOSP repositories. Since they are describing [the APIs as final](https://developer.android.com/preview/overview.html), I too consider them to be final and feel comfortable in recommending that people compile against them.  The "preview" aspect of it is more in terms of availability for other hardware, and that appears to be mostly a way to try to keep the dogs at bay for "why don't we have 7.1 for such-and-so Nexus device yet?" You are welcome to disagree and consider API Level 25 to be "not baked yet", but then you will need to come up with your own heuristics for what you consider to be "not baked yet" or not.

Prior to the L Developer Preview in 2014, for most Android releases, if the SDK shipped, it was final. Occasionally, it shipped after the OS was available to users.

> Likewise, I don't want a beta version of any Android support library, even if lint tells me one is available.

Lint should not be doing this; if you have evidence to the contrary, file an issue. Again, "beta version" will be designated as such. So, for example, the 25.0.0 editions of the support libraries are not a beta. If you wish to consider 25.0.0 to be beta, for whatever reason, you are welcome to do so, but then you will need to come up with your own heuristic for what is and is not beta.

> how do I determine what versions to specify in build.gradle for declarations such as the following?

For `compileSdkVersion`, set it to whatever you feel is stable. Right now, that could be 24. That could be 25.

For `targetSdkVersion`, set it to whatever makes sense for your app. This value is *specifically* designed to *not* strictly follow with the `compileSdkVersion`, for cases when you have an existing code base and need time to adapt the code to some newer behavior.

For support library versions, the major version should match your `compileSdkVersion`. Minor/patchlevels should be the latest available for that major version.

> Likewise, Android Studio's code analysis warns you if you have a dependency on a support library before 25.0.0, but doesn't mention that 25 is preview

That is because 25 is not preview. It only makes sense to use it once you set your `compileSdkVersion` to 25 — you may not be able to compile against it otherwise — but in all other respects it is as final as is any other support library update that is not specifically labelled as alpha, beta, RC, etc.

> Searching news outlets isn't ideal either because you need to manually sift through updated and out of date articles, especially with point releases like 7.1.1.

Android OS versions are announced on [the Android Developer Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/). For example, [here is the announcement about Android 7.0 starting to ship to devices](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/08/taking-final-wrapper-off-of-nougat.html).

Comment: The [preview timeline and updates](https://developer.android.com/preview/overview.html#timeline) section says "we’re delivering Developer Preview 1 as a Beta quality release" with final release in December. That's a pretty clear heuristic for not fully baked, although it may be close enough: "in general the builds are suitable for daily use by developers and early adopters". My personal experience hasn't been so good: the package manager doesn't even include the source code. I'd rather stick with the fully stable version while the new version stabilizes.

Comment: @EdwardBrey: "That's a pretty clear heuristic for not fully baked" -- IMHO, that is referring to the state of the OS on Nexus devices, not the state of the SDK. "in general the builds are suitable for daily use by developers and early adopters" -- the term "builds" refers to OS images, not the SDK. "the package manager doesn't even include the source code" -- that's not surprising, as that routinely lags.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the OS/SDK release status distinction. It looks like the issues with lint prompting to upgrade to pre-release code are resolved, and all that remains is the problem related to lagging distribution. I created an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=226469) to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best process I've been able to find:

1. Use the latest version from SDK Manager not marked as preview that has all the packages (images, source code, etc.) that are important to you. Use this version for `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion`, except when you need to hold back the target SDK version because your code doesn't account for a breaking change in the SDK.
2. Use the latest support library version posted on the [library revision history](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html) for the SDK version you're using.

It's not as automated as I'd would like, but at least it seems we can trust the prerelease packages in SDK Manager to be marked as such.